# C# Visual Basic Inheritance

Tags: c#, variables, unassigned-variable

I'm just getting started with C# and I've been stuck on this problem for two weeks. I have a main form that gets values from a class and a subclass.  My problem is that when I try to create an object of the CorporateClass VB tells me that two of my variables (CarSizeInteger and DiscountInteger) are unassigned.  My question is why. I implemented them earlier in the program.  Help! I'm hopelessly stuck!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace EX02_CarRentals
{
    public partial class RentalForm : Form
    {
        public RentalForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int DaysInteger, BeginningOdometerInteger, EndingOdometerInteger, CarSizeInteger, DiscountInteger;

            if (LicenseTextBox.Text != "")

                if (CompactRadioButton.Checked || MidSizeRadioButton.Checked || LuxuryRadioButton.Checked)
                {
                    int.TryParse(DaysRentedTextBox.Text, out DaysInteger);

                    int.TryParse(BeginningOdometerTextBox.Text, out BeginningOdometerInteger);

                    if (BeginningOdometerInteger > 0)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(EndingOdometerTextBox.Text, out EndingOdometerInteger);
                        if (EndingOdometerInteger > 0)
                        {
                            if (CompactRadioButton.Checked)
                                CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.Compact;

                            else if (MidSizeRadioButton.Checked)
                                CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.MidSize;

                            else CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.Luxury;
                        }
                        {
                            if (CorporateRadioButton.Checked || InsuranceRadioButton.Checked)
                            {
                                if (CorporateRadioButton.Checked)
                                    DiscountInteger = (int)Discount.Corporate;

                                else if (InsuranceRadioButton.Checked)
                                    DiscountInteger = (int)Discount.Insurance;

                                //create an instance of the Corporate Class
                                CorporateClass aCorpRental = new CorporateClass(BeginningOdometerInteger, EndingOdometerInteger, CarSizeInteger, DaysInteger, DiscountInteger);
                                AmountDueTextBox.Text = (aCorpRental.getAmountDue()).ToString("C");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //create an instance of the Rental Class

                                RentalRate ARental = new RentalRate(BeginningOdometerInteger, EndingOdometerInteger, CarSizeInteger, DaysInteger);
                                AmountDueTextBox.Text = (ARental.getAmountDue()).ToString("C");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void DaysRentedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm dying to know why you thought leaving your code all messed up like that was acceptable?

Comment: There really is little point suffixing 'Integer' to int variables.

Comment: FYI, in C# it is idiomatic to name local variables starting with lowercase. In neither C# nor VB is it a good idea to name variables with their type; the name of the variable should describe its *purpose*, not its storage.

Answer (score 7):

In C#, you cannot use the value of a variable before it's given a value, or you'll get the unassigned variable error. Let's see why your code is giving you that.

I'll focus on `CarSizeInteger`. There are three places where you attempt to initialize `CarSizeInteger`:

```
if (EndingOdometerInteger > 0)
{
    if (CompactRadioButton.Checked)
        CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.Compact;
    else if (MidSizeRadioButton.Checked)
        CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.MidSize;
    else CarSizeInteger = (int)CarSize.Luxury;
}
```

Note that all three of these assignment are contained within the `if (EndingOdometerInteger > 0)` block. In the case that `EndingOdometerInteger > 0` is false, *none* of the assignments will happen. Thus, when you try to use `CarSizeInteger` later, the compiler detects that it's possible for `CarSizeInteger` to be uninitialized, which is an error.

To avoid this error, you can give `CarSizeInteger` a default value:

```
int CarSizeInteger = 0;
```

or add an else block to your if statement which initializes `CarSizeInteger`:

```
if (EndingOdometerInteger > 0)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    CarSizeInteger = 0;
}
```

In any case, just make sure each of your variables is given a value before you tried to read its value.